# Define a default value when NULL in lookup

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a script that does a lookup on a website visitor.  Code is below.  I've discovered popup blockers will block the lookup and the values become null.  When this happens I end up with incomplete sentences in my website.  For Instance: "Hi there user from Baltimore, Maryland.  Welcome to the site!" Becomes, "Hi there user from  . Welcome to the site!"   I need to be able to have my span class use a default value.  Any idea what that syntax would look like?

Here is my code:

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
      $.getJSON('https://geolocation-db.com/json/')
         .done (function(location) {
            $('.country').html(location.country_name);
            $('.state').html(location.state);
            $('.city').html(location.city);
            $('.postal').html(location.postal);
            $('.latitude').html(location.latitude);
            $('.longitude').html(location.longitude);
            $('.ip').html(location.IPv4);
         });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hi there visitor from <span class="city"></span>, <span class="state"></span>.  Welcome to the site!</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: Of course, any assitance on how to have a default value AND bypass popup blockers would be incredible.

Comment: Why don't you just use the `country_name` instead?

Comment: This, for instance, will work: https://jsfiddle.net/7zrjbkof/

Comment: This was just a for instance, the "Hello visitor" is not really my syntax. I need help with creating a default value when the script doesn't run due to a pop up blocker.

Comment: I don't see any popup in your code...

Comment: @hev1 I suspect he's using the wrong term, and his actual problem is with the anti-tracking features of his adblocker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, maybe defining a default value on NULL isn't exactly what you want.  What you *actually* want is for your site to behave nicely when parts of it are being blocked.

Popup/ad/tracking blockers vary widely, so I'm going to go straight to dealing with the most severe blocking extension: NoScript.  With NoScript, JavaScript just doesn't run.  But your site can still work!

First, the easy solution to just make your site fall back to something sensible.  Put your default values directly in the HTML, like this:

```html
<h1>Hi there visitor from <span class="city">somewhere</span>, <span class="state">anywhere</span>.  Welcome to the site!</h1>
```

Your JavaScript can replace those defaults when it runs; if for any reason your JavaScript doesn't run, well at least the defaults are there.

**But to really bypass the blocking program...**

...do everything server-side.

You get the user's IP address when they request the website from your server.  Use this to send a server-to-server request to a geolocation service, then insert the results directly into the HTML as your webpage is generated.

This doesn't entirely excuse you from setting up fallbacks, because the geolocation service you use might go down, but no one's browser extension is going to be able to block you from doing it this way.

Granted, the Tor web browser will still be able to confuse your website as to where the user is located, but people who use Tor are generally delighted when they see websites reporting completely incorrect guesses as to where they're located.  Using Tor is a big commitment, let them have their fun. :)

Comment: This fixed it. And I would LOVE to do everything server side, but unfortunately my site is a hosted site that caters to high conversion templates and I don't have access to server side anything.  Great thought though.  If you want to see your answer working you can go to the site https://www.FullPriceForYourHouse.com.  My next hurdle is how to make sure when Google scans my site it takes that default value and doesn't scan it as "Mountain view, California" which messes with my search results.

Comment: @EddieMiddlebrooks Google doesn't run JavaScript, so I think you're already OK in that regard: Google will see whatever is in the HTML initially.

Comment: Well, there you go.  Nice easy solution.  I need more easy solutions in my life. ;)  Thanks for all your help.  This was brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you want to use a default value if a property in a JS object doesn't exist, the easy way is to use `||`.

```
$('.city').html(location.city || 'the moon');
```

That will treat most forms of "nothing" (a blank string, the number zero, null, or missing entirely) the same.  If you only want to use the default in some of those cases, or you want to change other text based on whether the property is blank (i.e. remove the comma), you'll need to check for those specifically.  (The `?:` operator can help with that).

Comment: So I tried this, but when I turn on the pop up blocker the info is still blank, this tells me that the site may be parsing the entire script as a pop up, not just the external info source link.

Comment: @EddieMiddlebrooks Changing `.done` to `.always` will allow this answer to do what it's meant to do, but I've realized that dealing with a blocking extension demands a very different solution, so I've posted that as a separate answer.

Comment: Thank you!  I was able to solve the issue even from complete script failure by putting the default value in this way:  <span class="state">Florida</span>  in that structure there's always a default entry.  Unfortunately there is about a micro second or so where a visitor can see the default data before the script finishes loading and I'd like to solve for that, but it's working nonetheless.  I will research the difference between .done and .always.  Thanks for the information.